# PHP ajax json on iis

Tags: php, ajax, json, iis, post

New to project and php..Environment IIS 7.5

Trying to get script to retrieve pw to work on IIS.

Link

submitAJAX

```
function submitAJAX(iPage, iData, iSync) {
if (iSync == null) {
        iSync = true;
}
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        dataType: "json",
        url: iPage,
        global: true,
        async: iSync, 
        data: iData, 
        success: function(data, textStatus) {
            handleAJAXResponse(data, textStatus);
                }
});

}
```

ajax.js

```
var templateForm;
var desinationForm;
var containerForm;
/*
Wrapper for the JQuery AJAX .post function
*/
function submitAJAX(iPage, iData, iSync) {
    if (iSync == null) {
        iSync = true;
}
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        dataType: "json",
        url: iPage,
        global: true,
        async: iSync, 
        data: iData, 
        success: function(data, textStatus) {
            handleAJAXResponse(data, textStatus);
                }
});

}


/*
Handle the JQuery AJAX Post response
*/
function handleAJAXResponse(jsonObj, textStatus) {


    // Update the destination form
    if ((templateForm) && (desinationForm)) {

        desinationForm.html(templateForm.html());
        containerForm = desinationForm.attr('id');
    }

    templateForm = '';
    desinationForm = '';

    if (textStatus == 'success') {

        processJSONData(jsonObj, containerForm);

    } else {
        alert('AJAX Execution Error: ' + textStatus);
    }   
}


/*
Process the specified JSON data object
*/
function processJSONData(iJSON, iContainer) {

    $.each(iJSON, function(iVariable, iValue) {
        if (iValue) {
            if (iContainer) {
                var tmpObj = $('#' + iContainer + ' #' + iVariable);
                //if (!tmpObj.size()) { var tmpObj = $('#' + iContainer + " [name=" + iVariable + "]"); }
                //if (!tmpObj.size()) { var tmpObj = $('#' + iContainer + " [id*=" + iVariable + "]"); }
                //if (!tmpObj.size()) { var tmpObj = $('#' + iContainer + " [name*=" + iVariable + "]"); }

            } else {            
                var tmpObj = $('#' + iVariable);
                //if (!tmpObj.size()) { var tmpObj = $("[name=" + iVariable + "]"); }
                //if (!tmpObj.size()) { var tmpObj = $("[id*=" + iVariable + "]"); }
                //if (!tmpObj.size()) { var tmpObj = $("[name*=" + iVariable + "]"); }
            }

            // If the current object is another JSON oject
            if ((typeof iValue == 'object') && (iValue.toString().indexOf('object') > -1)) {
                if (iContainer) {
                    processJSONData(iValue, iContainer + ' #' + iVariable);
                } else {
                    processJSONData(iValue, iVariable);
                }

            } else {
                //alert(iContainer + '.' + iVariable + ' = ' + iValue + ' : ' + tmpObj.size());

                // Object exists on the page
                if (tmpObj.size()) {
                    setFieldValue(tmpObj, iValue);

                // Object doesn't exist on the page
                } else {
                    // Check for a JS function
                    if (iVariable.indexOf('script_') == 0) {
                        setTimeout(iValue, 10);
                        //eval(iValue);

                    // Check for a form validation error
                    } else if (iVariable.indexOf('_error') > -1) {
                        setFormError(iVariable.replace('_error', ''));

                    } else {
                        //alert('AJAX Variable Error: ' + iVariable);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}


function setFieldValue(iFieldObj, iValue) {
    switch (iFieldObj.attr('type')) {
        case 'text':
        case 'password':
        case 'file':
        case 'hidden':
        case 'submit':
        case 'button':
        case 'reset':
        case 'textarea':
        case 'select-multiple':
            iFieldObj.val(iValue);
            //alert($(tmpObj).fieldValue());
            break;

        case 'checkbox':
            if (!iFieldObj.attr('checked')) {
                iFieldObj.trigger('click');
            } else {
                //iFieldObj.attr('checked', false);
            }
            break;

        case 'select-one':
            iFieldObj.val(iValue);
            break;

        case 'radio':
            $("input[name=" + iFieldObj.attr('id') + "]").each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == iValue) {
                    $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
                }
            });
            break;

        default:
            if ((document.getElementById(iFieldObj.attr('id')).type == 'select-one') || (document.getElementById(iFieldObj.attr('id')).type == 'select-multiple')) {
                iFieldObj.val(iValue);

            } else if (iFieldObj.attr('id')) {
                iFieldObj.html(iValue);
            }
            break;
    }
}


/*
Add the error classes to the specified field
*/
function setFormError(iErrorName) {
    if (iErrorName.indexOf(']') > 0) {
        var tmpData = iErrorName.split('[');
        var tmpIndex = 0;

        for (i = 1; i < tmpData.length; i ++) {
            tmpData[i] = tmpData[i].replace(']', '');
            //if ((tmpData[i] * 1) == 0) { tmpData[i] = 1; }
            tmpIndex = tmpIndex + (tmpData[i] * 1);
        }

        //alert(tmpData[0] + '\n' + tmpIndex);      
        $('[id*=' + tmpData[0] + ']:input').eq(tmpIndex).addClass('errorElem');
        $('[id*=' + tmpData[0] + '_label]').eq(tmpIndex).addClass('errorCell');

    } else {
        $('#' + iErrorName).addClass('errorElem');
        //$("[name=" + iErrorName + "]").addClass('errorElem');
        $('#' + iErrorName + '_label').addClass('errorCell');           
    }

    if ($('#updateMsgDescription').size() == 0) {
        if (containerForm) {
            $('#' + containerForm + ' #updateMsg').after('<div id="updateMsgDescription"></div>');
        } else {
            $('#updateMsg').after('<div id="updateMsgDescription"></div>');
        }
    }

    /*
    var tmpItem = replace($('#' + iErrorName + '_label').html(), ':', '');
    tmpItem = Trim(tmpItem.replace(/<\/?(?!\!)[^>]*>/gi, ''));

    if (tmpItem != '') {
        $('#updateMsgDescription').html($('#updateMsgDescription').html() + '<br>&bull; ' + tmpItem);
    }
    */
}


/*
Clean all error elements in the specified form
*/
function clearFormErrors(iFormObj) {
    $('.errorElem').removeClass('errorElem');
    $('.errorCell').removeClass('errorCell');
}


/*
The error element has been focused so clear any error objects
*/
function cleanFormError(iErrorObj) {
    /*
    var tmpName = iErrorObj.id || iErrorObj.name || iErrorObj.attr('id') || iErrorObj.attr('name');
    if (tmpName) {
        $('#' + tmpName).removeClass('errorElem');
        //$("[name=" + tmpName + "]").removeClass('errorElem');
        $('#' + tmpName + '_label').removeClass('errorCell');
    }
    */

    $(iErrorObj).removeClass('errorElem');
    $(iErrorObj).parent().parent().find('#' + $(iErrorObj).attr('id') + '_label').removeClass('errorCell');
}


/*
Disable a form button, and set updating display label
*/
function doFormSubmit(iDisplay, iForm, iDisabledBtn) {
    if (iDisabledBtn == null) {
        iDisabledBtn = true;
    }

    var tmpName = iForm.name || iForm.id || iForm.attr('id');

    containerForm = tmpName;

    // Clear all form errors
    clearFormErrors(iForm);

    var tmpType = $(iForm).attr("enctype");

    if (tmpType == 'multipart/form-data') {
        //alert('file upload');

    } else {
        if (iDisabledBtn) {
            $('#' + tmpName + ' #updateBtn').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    }

    $('#updateMsgDescription').remove();

    //$('#' + tmpName + ' #updateBtn').attr('disabled', true);
    iDisplay = replace(iDisplay, '...', '<img src=\'images/progress_dots.gif\'>');  
    $('#' + tmpName + ' #updateMsg').html('<span class="btext12">' + iDisplay + '</span><br><br>');
}


/*
Show a data form for the specified form
*/
function showDataForm(iID, iFormName, iFileName) {
    var Now = new Date();
    var Start = Now.getTime()

    // Remove all existing update forms
    //$('[id*=update_]').html('');
    //$('[id*=image_]').attr('src', '/images/plus_box.gif');

    toggleLinks('update_' + iID, 'image_' + iID); 

    if (($('#image_' + iID).attr('src')).indexOf('minus') == -1) {
        return false;
    }

    $('#update_' + iID).html('<br><center><b>Loading data...</b></center><br>'); 

    var tmpAddress = window.location.href;
    if (tmpAddress.indexOf('?') > 0) {
        var tmpDat = tmpAddress.split('?');
        tmpAddress = tmpDat[0];
    }

    templateForm = $('#' + iFormName);
    desinationForm = $('#update_' + iID);

    if (iFileName == null) {
        submitAJAX(tmpAddress + 'add_new.php?action=XML_GET', 1);
        //alert(tmpAddress + 'add_new.php?action=XML_GET', { 0: iID });
    } else {
        submitAJAX(iFileName, {0: iID});
    }

    var Now = new Date();
    //alert((Now.getTime() - Start));

    //setTimeout('alert($(\'#update_1 #user_id\').fieldValue());', 2000);
}
```

I am having issues with other functions using this. What happens when running it is Finding Password... is displayed but it sits there.

Thanks for taking a look,
Doug

Comment: Can this be narrowed down anymore...? And what do you mean just sits there?

Comment: That sure is a lot of code for your small description of the problem.

Comment: clicking the link displays "Finding Password..." then nothing happens. Sorry for all the code I wanted to include all functions used.

Comment: I double posted the submitAJAX as it was included in ajax.js, sorry.

Comment: The link didnt post that calls this<input type="submit" id="updateBtn" class="registerBtn" value="Find Password" style="width: 125px;" onclick="doFormSubmit('Finding Password...', this.form); submitAJAX('../index.php?action=FORGOT_PASSWORD', $('#password_frm').serialize());">